# Websitebaker menu fail

Tags: css, menu, xhtml, websitebaker

in my xHTML the menu works great, but when I upload it to my website baker the menu fails.

xHTML Preview: http://eyesondesign.nl/xhtml/

Websitebaker Preview: http://eyesondesign.nl/baker/

When im using the xHTML code for website baker then it works fine :)

**xHTML Coding:**

```
<div id="hoofdmenubalk">
            <a href="#" class="hoofdmenu">Home</a><span class="tussenstukhoofd"></span>
            <a href="#" class="hoofdmenu">Biografie</a><span class="tussenstukhoofd"></span>
            <a href="#" class="hoofdmenu">Band</a><span class="tussenstukhoofd"></span>
            <a href="#" class="hoofdmenu">Muziek</a><span class="tussenstukhoofd"></span>
            <a href="#" class="hoofdmenu">Tour</a><span class="tussenstukhoofd"></span>
            <a href="#" class="hoofdmenu">Contact</a><span class="tussenstukhoofd"></span>
        </div>
```

**Website Baker code:**

```
<div id="hoofdmenubalk">
        <?php show_menu(1); ?>
    </div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
a.hoofdmenu {
font-family:Arial;
font-size: 14px;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration:none;
padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
line-height:40px;
```

}

```
a.hoofdmenu:hover {
    font-family:Arial;
    color: #f6f685;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-image:url('afbeeldingen/submenu.jpg'); 
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
}

a.hoofdmenu:active {
    color: #f6f685;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.menu {
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-type:none;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
}

li {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you still working on this? What is the output you get with show_menu? I see no menu on that site you linked to. 
show_menu has many options/parameters, you can get almost any output you like with it.